# A twisted hypergeometric series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n}\left(\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}\right)^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function, polylogarithm

**Question.** I was given that $$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n}\left(\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}\right)^2=\frac{32}\pi G\ln2+\frac{64}\pi\Im\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)-2\ln^22-\frac53\pi^2$$ where $H_n$ harmonic numbers, $G$ Catalan and $\operatorname{Li}_n$ polylogarithm. How can it be proved?

**My Approach.** Using $\int_0^1x^{n-1}\ln(1-x)dx=-\frac{H_n}n$ one have
$$S=\int_0^1-\ln(1-x)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}\right)^2x^{n-1}dx
=\int_0^1-\ln(1-x)\left(\frac2\pi\frac{\mathbf{K}(x)}x-\frac1x\right)dx$$ where $\mathbf{K}$ denotes elliptic integral of the first kind. The question boils down to finding $$\int_0^1\frac{\mathbf{K}(x)\ln(1-x)}xdx$$ For this integral, I tried to use the integral representation of the elliptic integral and got: $$\int_{(0,1)^3}\frac{dxdydz}{\sqrt{1-y^2}\sqrt{1-xy^2}(zx-1)}$$ This is the furthermost step I can get.

Comment: Perhaps it was a typo, but Catalans constant is defined as $$\mathrm G=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}$$

Comment: Sorry for that. I have corrected it.

Comment: Although I'm almost certain I have encountered this one before (but my mind might been tricked) I wasn't able to find it again. However, while searching I stumbled upon lots and lots of related sums (together with proofs for their values!) and would like to share them. Especially the work of *John M. Campbell* is quite fruitful, see for example [here](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01364815v2/document) and [here](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01774708/document). Moreover [this website](http://www.pi314.net/eng/index.php) contains some very interesting sums (also closey related!).

Comment: I start trying to prove, by using the second link of mrtaurho starting with equation 2.1 and the identity $$\text{Hypergeometric2F1}\left[\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},3,z\right]==\frac{16 (-2 \text{EllipticE}[z]+(2-z) \text{EllipticK}[z])}{\pi  z^2}$$.

Comment: who gave you this series/where did you find it?

Comment: @clathratus I found that in a discussion group of definite integrals of my country.

Comment: BTW: \begin{align}\int_0^1x^{n-1}\ln(1-x)dx=-\frac{H_n}n,\end{align}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One have FL expansion
$$\small K(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{2 P_n(2 x-1)}{2 n+1},\ \  \frac{\log (1-x)}{x}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } 2 (-1)^{n-1} (2 n+1) P_n(2 x-1) \left(\sum _{k=n+1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^2}\right)$$
Thus by orthogonal relation of Legendre polynomial and series-integral conversion one have:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{K(x) \log (1-x)}{x} \, dx=16 \int_0^1 \frac{\log (x) \tanh ^{-1}(x)}{x^2+1} \, dx$$
RHS has a polylogarithmic primitive (up to trilog) hence trivial.