# Binomial Euler sums: Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{4^n}\binom{2n}n\frac{H_n^{(s_1)}\cdots H_n^{(s_k)}}{n^s}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, closed-form, harmonic-numbers, euler-sums

Denote $$f(s;s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_k)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{4^n}\binom{2n}n\frac{H_n^{(s_1)}\cdots H_n^{(s_k)}}{n^s}$$
Can $f(\cdots)$ always be represented as $\mathbb Q$-linear combination of alternating Euler sum of weight $W$? Here $s$ and $s_i$ are positive integers and $W=s+\sum_i s_i$. Alternating Euler sums are defined as $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{l(n-1)}\frac{H_n^{(s_1)}\cdots H_n^{(s_k)}}{n^s},$$ where $l=0,1$ and $s,s_i\in\mathbb Z^+$.

> By Editor: Examples and related things: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3184675/evaluating-sum-n-1-infty-frach-n2n-frac-binom2nn4n), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3221131/a-twisted-hypergeometric-series-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nn-left-frac2n?rq=1), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3425231/prove-zeta3-2-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nn-left-frac14n2n-choose-n-le), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3306742/infinite-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac4nh-nn22n-choose-n), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2895620/an-euler-type-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frach-n2n-cdot-4n2n-choose-n), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3085293/closed-form-expression-for-the-harmonic-sum-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frach), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3249148/a-series-involving-binomial-coefficient-and-harmonic-number).

> By Editor again: Harder examples and generalizations: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3730982/fourier-legendre-expansion-for-frac-textli-2xx-frac-log-21-xx/3732277#3732277), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3730956/evaluate-int-01-log-1-x-3f-2-left1-1-1-frac32-frac32x-right/3733570#3733570), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3734886/f-l-expansion-sum-n-0-infty-left-frac-binom2-nn4n-right2), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3736208/evaluate-frac12-int-01-log-2x-3f-2-left1-1-1-frac32-frac32).

**Numerical Evidence and Motivation**
I did some calculation of this binomial sum of small $n$'s. The table in the appendix is a part of that.
I also did some research on alternating Euler sum. The constants involved in the alt. Euler sums are exactly the same when $n\le4$. I randomly chose and evaluated some sums of weight $5$ and found that their constants are again same.

**Possible Conversion**
Although I noticed $\frac1{4^n}\binom{2n}n=\frac2\pi\int_0^1(4x-4x^2)^{n-1/2}dx$, I'm unsure about how to convert it into the whole sum into an integral and then (possibly making some substitution?) convert it into the form of alternating Euler sum.

**Appendix**
The number in the blanks are the coefficients.
\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
&\ln2\\\hline
f(1)&2\\\hline
\end{array}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
&\zeta(2)&\ln^22\\\hline
f(2)&1&-2\\\hline
f(1;1)&2&0\\\hline
\end{array}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
&\zeta(3)&\zeta(2)\ln2&\ln^32\\\hline
f(3)&2&-2&\frac43\\\hline
f(2;1)&\frac92&-4&0\\\hline
f(1;2)&\frac32&0&0\\\hline
f(1;1^2)&\frac{21}2&0&0\\\hline
\end{array}

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
&\zeta(4)&\zeta(3)\ln2&\zeta(2)\ln^22&\ln^42&\operatorname{Li}_4(1/2)\\\hline
f(4)&\frac94&-4&2&-\frac23&0\\\hline
f(3;1)&-\frac{13}4&-2&2&\frac13&8\\\hline
f(2;2)&3&-3&0&0&0\\\hline
f(2;1^2)&-14&7&-8&\frac43&32\\\hline
f(1;3)&\frac{37}4&-7&2&-\frac13&-8\\\hline
f(1;2,1)&\frac{49}4&-7&2&-\frac13&-8\\\hline
f(1;1^3)&\frac{115}4&35&-10&\frac53&40\\\hline
\end{array}